# How can I plot a histogram of discrete distribution on tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm using tensorboard (tensorflow 1.1.0) to show the result of my CNN classifier.

I added some output vector as tf.summary.histogram in order to show the counts of output in each bin, but tensorboard seems to automatically compute interpolation and show them as (somehow) smoothed distribution
(and therefore I can not find the exact counts for the bins).

Could someone tell me how can I avoid the interpolation and show usual histograms using bars?

Answer (score 0):

I not sure that there is easy way to do it.

I very unsure in below text, correct me if I wrong.

From this file https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/plugins/histogram/vz_histogram_timeseries/index.html it seems that histogram comes to tensorboard in double values.
Summary op uses either histogram from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/ops/histogram_ops.py (1) or https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/core/lib/histogram/histogram.cc (2)

I suppose that it uses 2nd because here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/summary/summary.py#L189 it calls function from generated file. In my package code in this generated file there is another function call:

```
result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("HistogramSummary", tag=tag, values=values,
                              name=name)
```

I have grep all repo and seems like there is no other python code which define something with "HistogramSummary", so it seems like it's really defined here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/core/kernels/summary_op.cc and this code uses code mentioned above (2).

So, it seems to me that histogram which is used now is buried deep inside of framework and I not sure that it's easy to rewrite it.

In this page there is email for support https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/summary . I suppose that it's better to contact this person or make issue on github.

Comment: As temporary dirty hack you can just draw needed percentiles using usual scalars or just plot all data with matplotlib and use image summary.